# I have been having issues in implementing a filter of item categories in an ecommerce being built using NodeJs and Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, filter, angular2-ngmodel

In the following
code snippets you the filter functions doesn't work.
Component HTML:

```
<div class="products-page">
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-3">
     <h4>Categories</h4>
     <div class="p-field-checkbox" *ngFor="let category of categories">
        <label for="{{category.id}}">{{category.name}}</label>
        <p-checkbox
        [(ngModel)]="category.checked"
        binary="true"
        [inputId]="category.id"
        (onChange)="categoryFilter()"
      ></p-checkbox>
      <label for="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.name }}</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
        <div class="grid" *ngIf="products">
            <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let product of products">

                <eshop-frontend-product-item [product] ="product"></eshop-frontend-product-item>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductsService } from '../../services/products.service';
import { Product } from '../../models/product';
import { CategoriesService } from '../../services/categories.service';
import { Category } from '../../models/category';

@Component({
  selector: 'eshop-frontend-products-list',
  templateUrl: './products-list.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class ProductsListComponent implements OnInit {
  isChecked = false
  products: Product[] = [];
  categories: Category[] = [];

  constructor(private prodService: ProductsService, private catService: CategoriesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._getProducts();
    this._getCategories();
  }

  private _getProducts(categoriesFilter?: string[]) {
    this.prodService.getProducts(categoriesFilter).subscribe((resProducts) => {
      this.products = resProducts;
    });
  }

  private _getCategories(){
    this.catService.getCategories().subscribe(resCats =>{
      this.categories = resCats;
    })
  }

  categoryFilter() {
    const selectedCategories: string | any = this.categories
      .filter((category) => category.checked)
      .map((category) => category.id);

    this._getProducts(selectedCategories);
  }


}
```

Products Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';
import { Product } from '../models/product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ProductsService {
  apiUrlProducts = environment.apiURL + 'products';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getProducts(categoriesFilter?: string[]): Observable<Product[]> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (categoriesFilter) {
      params = params.append('categories', categoriesFilter.join(','));
    }
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.apiUrlProducts, { params: params });
  }



  createProduct(productData: FormData): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.post<Product>(this.apiUrlProducts, productData);
  }

  getProduct(productId: string): Observable<Product> {
   return this.http.get<Product>(`${this.apiUrlProducts}/${productId}`);
 }

  updateProduct(productData: FormData, productid: string): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.put<Product>(`${this.apiUrlProducts}/${productid}`, productData);
  }


deleteProduct(productId: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.delete<any>(`${this.apiUrlProducts}/${productId}`);
}

getProductsCount(): Observable<number> {
  return this.http
    .get<number>(`${this.apiUrlProducts}/get/count`)
    .pipe(map((objectValue: any) => objectValue.productCount));
}

getFeaturedProducts(): Observable<Product[]>{
  return this.http.get<Product[]>(`${this.apiUrlProducts}/get/featured/`);
}
}
```

Errors:

[(ngModel)]="category.checked"
Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Category';

[inputId]="category.id"
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

In the backend i do not have the checked field, I was under the impression that it was not necessary to add it, I have also witnessed several example where this is not implemented and still works fine. I have been stuk for a long time and there seems to be nothing useful out there, can you please advise?

Comment: please dont post pics, post code

Comment: @MWO sorry fairly new to this. Anyway it still throws the same error, do I have to edit the backend  to add checked? It surely doesn't seem like a practical solution

Answer (score 0):

1. > [(ngModel)]="category.checked" Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Category';

You can check in your interface in `import { Category } from '../../models/category';` if there a property called checked. Otherwise, add the "checked" property to the category interface.

2. > [inputId]="category.id" Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Again check your Category interface, maybe the property "id" has a type like that string | undefined. Remove the "| undefined" and it sould work.

Answer (score 0):

`models/category.ts`:

```
export class Category {
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    icon?: string;
    color?: string;
    checked?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.